# Retrieving image from database and showing it Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a web application in the Laravel Framework. I have written code that saves a image in the database.

Code for saving a image in the database (code in my controller):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {       
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
        ]);
  
        $user = request()->user();
        $assortment = $user->assortments()->create($request->all());


        if($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
            if($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
                //dd($request->image->store('images', 'public'));
                $assortment->image_path = $request->image->store('images', 'public');
                $assortment->save();
                
                //Check what the Storage::url() generates
                //dd(Storage::disk('public')->url($assortment->fresh()->image_path));
                }
                else {
                abort(500, "Image not valid");
                }
            }
        
         if ($request->wantsJson()) {
             return response([], 204);
        }

        return redirect()->route('assortments.show', $assortment->slug)
                        ->with('success','Verzameling is succesvol aangemaakt.');

        
    }
```

I want my image to be retrieved from my database in the view but I do not know how to go about doing this. I tried things like:

`<img src="/images/{{ $imageVariableName }}">` *Variables and path are changed*

The view I am trying to make my image be retrieved and shown:

```xml
<div class="mt-10">
    <ul class="md:grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-x-8 md:gap-y-10">
        @foreach ($assortment->itemCategories as $category)
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('categories.show', [$assortment->slug, $category->id]) }}">
                    <div class="flex px-4 py-5 bg-white shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md sm:px-6">
                        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                            <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-md bg-indigo-500 text-white">
                                <!-- Heroicon name: globe-alt -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-4">
                            <h4 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">{{ $category->name }}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Anyone know how I go about doing this?

**EDIT**

I also tried:

`<img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url($assortment->image_path) }}">`

But it also returned no image. Just returned:

[image]

I inspected the image and it returned the following link:

http://localhost/storage/tmp/phpSX2W3G

**EDIT**

I know now the problem has to do with my upload controller. The file should not be stored at a temporary path: `/storage//tmp/phpL1ZVcx`

**EDIT 2**

The storage link appears to be broken. Get this in my `public/storage`:

[image]
Greetings,

Parsa

Comment: When your image is saved, do you see the file in your public folder? You're not storing inside `/images/`, so that won't work either. Have you made changes to your `filesystem.php`? If you did, please share the configuration.

Comment: It is saved in the public folder inside my storage. I have not made changes to my `filesystem.php`

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<img src={{Storage::url($assortment->img)}} />
```

EDIT:
I found out your problem, the problem not in the display but actually in your upload code

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image'); //request the file
    $fileName = md5($image->getClientOriginalName() . microtime()) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); //use md5 for security reasons and get the extension.
    $image->storeAs('', $fileName, 'public'); //store the file in the public folder disk.

    $assortment->image_path = $fileName;
    $assortment->save();
}
```

should become, because $filename just a temporary upload file it will be delete later, the actual upload path will be return by storeAs

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image'); //request the file
    $fileName = md5($image->getClientOriginalName() . microtime()) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); //use md5 for security reasons and get the extension.

    $assortment->image_path = $image->storeAs('', $fileName, 'public'); //store the file in the public folder disk.
    $assortment->save();
}
```

---

EDIT2: if you are using nginx you need to remove these line

```
        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
               expires 365d;
        }
```

Comment: Hi man, this did not work for me. I also tried: `<img src="{{ asset('img/upload/' . $assortment->image_path) }}">` but this did not help as well.

Comment: change Storge Folder CH mod  777 ?

Comment: one note, if you are using nginx then you need removing "location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$"

Comment: @PhúcHậuTrần I also believe it has to do with my upload code. Let me check out if it works I will keep you updated :)

Comment: Hi @PhúcHậuTrần. I tried the code. I ran the test I have to see if the code works and it does. However, the image is not retrieved. I am using nginx. What is it I need to remove?

Comment: Hi @PhúcHậuTrần. I was unable to find that line of code in my nginx config file.

Comment: Also, I think the file should not be stored in this temporary path: `/storage//tmp/phpL1ZVcx` which is the problem I am facing,

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below:

Have included comments in the code with `dd()` statements to debug - uncomment the dd() statements if you don't get it working to check.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{       
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
    ]);
  
    $user = request()->user();

    if(!$user) {
        abort(401, 'Unauthenticated');
    }

    $assortment = $user->assortments()->create($validated);


    if($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
        //dd($request->image->store('images', 'public'));
        $assortment->image_path = $request->image->store('images', 'public');
        $assortment->save();
                
        //Check what the Storage::url() generates
        //dd(Storage::disk('public')->url($assortment->fresh()->image_path));
    } else {
        abort(422, "Image not valid");
    }
            
        
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        return response([], 204);
    }

    return redirect()->route('assortments.show', $assortment->slug)
        ->with('success','Verzameling is succesvol aangemaakt.');

        
}
```

Verify that you have a `public` disk configured in the `config\filesystems.php`, something like

```php
'public' => [
    'driver'     => 'local',
    'root'       => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url'        => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],

//And links specified for symlinking when php artisan storage:link is run

'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Then run

```sh
php artisan storage:link
```

and check in the `public` folder that there exists a symlinked `storage` folder

Then in your blade view, you can use

```
<img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url($assortment->image_path) }}" />

//OR

<img src="/storage/{{ $assortment->image_path }}" />
```

Comment: Hi. I tried your code but it does not work. When I try to do the `dd()` it returns the following back to me: `Error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found
`

Comment: @Parsa_237 You need to import `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;` at the top in the controller class file.

Comment: Ok. The `dd()` works now and returns the following: `"/storage/images/tVr4gaKyl5BuLY4U3QRiISdtnQ2kkxRhOho776o2.jpeg"`. But no image is still retrieved.

Comment: Can you check if there's a symlinked `storage` folder visible in your `public` directory. Also try to clear the compiled views by running `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: In my `public` folder there is a `storage` folder. When I click on it however, it says the link `storage` is broken.

Comment: Try to fix the symlink by running `php artisan storage:link` again. Which os are you on mac/linux/win?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu (Linux). I tried to fix it like that multiple times. But it just returns: `The [/var/www/public/storage] link already exists.
The links have been created.`

Comment: Okay first remove the symlink by running `cd <root-of-project>/public` and `unlink storage`. Then check that you don't see the `storage` folder in the `public` directory. Then cd back to the root of your application and run `php artisan storage:link` and check again

Comment: What is the exact command for unlinking storage? I tried: `php artisan storage:unlink` but that did not work. Working in Laradock, can I not manually delete `storage` from the `public` folder? So `rm storage`

Comment: Yes you can `rm storage` and manually delete the symlink from the `public`folder. For unkinking a symlink in linux you can `unlink pubic/storage` or just `rm public/storage` from the root directory of your project. `php artisan storage:link` is just a wrapper which creates the symlinks as per the associations declared under the `links` key in the `config\filesystems.php` file. You could also create the symlink manually by running `ln -s storage/app/public public/storage` from the root directory of your project

Comment: `The [/var/www/public/storage] link has been connected to [/var/www/storage/app/public].
The links have been created.` The link has been created again. What do I have to do now?

Comment: Great now check whether you are able to see the image file in `public/storage` symlinked folder. Then you must be able to see the image in the view using `<img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url($assortment->image_path) }} />` or by just tacking `<img src="/storage/{{ $assortment->image_path}} />`

Comment: I uploaded an image again. But the `storage` file said that the `storage` link was broken again. I'm talking about the `storage` file in `application/public/storage`. In `storage/app/images` and `storage/app/public' I also did not find any image. Image is also not retrieved. `dd()` returns the following: `"/storage/images/j5hI3EMmppDjcoR4OWX5rTA552iDRMhmm7IjW3uE.jpeg"`. Check question edit as well please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227423/discussion-between-donkarnash-and-parsa-237).

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
             
            $assortment->image_path = $image->store('', 'public');
            $assortment->save();
        }
```

*NB: Laravel by default will create a unique name for a file and manage extension for you - dependent on your use case you may not need to make this filename yourself.*

---

**Artisan Command**

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Generates the correct symlinks for your public storage.

---

**Template**

```
{{ Storage::url($assortment->image_path) }}
```

Those three things together should work.

Comment: If not - can you provide the output of `Storage::url($assortment->image_path`

Comment: You mean `dd()`? I did element inspect on the element and it showed this link: `/storage//tmp/php0Izlpp`

Comment: Is that using the above exact controller method? Is the database value being saved as /php0Izlpp?  It shouldn't be with the above.

Comment: Yes that exact controller method is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`<img src="{{ url('storage/images/'.$assortment->image_path) }}"/>`

Comment: Hi man! This did not work for me. Still no image returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try a much simplified version:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $path = $request->file('image')->storePublicly('images'); // Store file in public disk & return path
    $assortment->image_path = $path; // If you want filename only, use basename($path)
    $assortment->save();
}
```

After that, you can use `Storage::disk('public')->url($assortment->image_path)` in your view. Using `getClientOriginalExtension()` and `getClientOriginalExtension()` probably isn't a good idea since it's not considered a *safe value* ([source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php#L90)). Laravel's store method saves the file and returns the hashed filename with path for you so you don't have to worry about all that :)

Make sure storage symlink is created:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Also make sure `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini` are set with sufficient amount.

Comment: The simplified version for the controller does not work for me. When I run my test `testUserCanUploadFile` the test fails.

Comment: Which part of it isn't working for you? Do note that it's saving into `/images` directory rather than public root. Could be the reason your test failed.

Comment: It is not saved in my `public` folder at all. Neither in my `/images` directory. When I checked my web source code and checked my image element. It showed a temporary link where the file is saved. It should show a filename. This has to do with my `store()` controller I believe.

Comment: That's very strangle. I tested the above code before posting here. The store methods are from Laravel's anyway. Have you verified your PHP settings for `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`? Also have you tried on a different environment?

Comment: I think that if it was due to the file size, I would get an error regarding that. It has to due with my `store()` method controller. I am positive about that. One of the answers also was about the controller. But the code provided with it did not work.